# scanf() is getting stuck on final use

Tags: c

I'm trying to use scanf to assign values to some integers but whichever scanner I put last will get suck as if it it wasn't seeing the new line. I've tried flushing the input buffer before every scan, but its hasn't helped. Do i need to malloc the pointers, even if they are being passed as the address of an existing variable out of function?

code:

```
void settings(int *x, int *y, int *l, int *m){
printf("Please enter the size of the game board (e.g. 3x6): ");
scanf("%dx%d",x,y);
printf("Please select the level of the game (0-9): ");
scanf("%d",l);
printf("Please enter the largest card value (1-99): ");
scanf("%d",m);
printf("Please enter the seed of the random number generator: (0-9999): ");
int s;
scanf("%d",&s);
srand(s);
return;}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your program is stuck where you think it is? Try printing something (including a newline so it's flushed) after the `scanf` call.

Comment: @psyco: Nope; look at how those variables are defined.

Comment: Add `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf();` Add `#include<stdio.h> #include<stdlib.h>`   If that does not fix, problem is in the rest of the code, not here.

Comment: @ScottHunter. Thanks for pointing out. I almost forgot the function prototype.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) use meaningful variable and parameter names.  meaningful names indicate content or usage or (better) both.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: all of the inputs are expecting a positive integer.  Therefore, the variables in the caller, the parameters on the function signature,all need to be `unsigned int` rather than `int`.  For the calls to `scanf()` use "%u"  rather than "%d".

Comment: the '%d' (or better '%u') format specifier will consume any leading white space (like a newline).  Please post what your actual input looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it should work.
Pay attention that your pointers should be initialized before the call, they can't be NULL:

```
    int *x = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *y = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *l = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *m = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));


    settings(x,y,l,m);
```

No problem besides that...

Comment: Will this work if i'm just passing the address of an initialized variable? or should i just work with them as pointers

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()`.

Comment: You should just work with them as a pointers... sorry for the delay @nkoenigs